# show that $\alpha\left(k\right)\ :=\ \left(1-\tfrac{1}{k}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)k}-\left(1-\tfrac{2}{k}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)k}$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

As a follow up for : [Let $k\in\mathbb{N},$ Show that there is $i\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $\ \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{i}-\left(1-\frac{2}{k}\right)^{i}\geq \frac{1}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748040/let-k-in-mathbbn-show-that-there-is-i-in-mathbbn-s-t-left1-frac1?noredirect=1#comment10074764_4748040)

show that $\alpha\left(k\right)\ :=\ \left(1-\tfrac{1}{k}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)k}-\left(1-\tfrac{2}{k}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)k}$ is decreasing for $k\in\left[3,\infty\right)$

thing I've tried:
showing that first derivative is non-positive, but I've got complicated expression i cannot handle with ($k = x $):

$\dfrac{\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)\,x}\,\left(\ln\left(2\right)\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\left(x-1\right)+\ln\left(2\right)\right)}{x-1}-\dfrac{\left(\frac{x-2}{x}\right)^{\ln\left(2\right)\,x}\,\left(\ln\left(2\right)\ln\left(\frac{x-2}{x}\right)\left(x-2\right)+2\ln\left(2\right)\right)}{x-2}$

trying to compare
$\alpha\left(k\right)\ with$ $ \alpha\left(k+1\right)\ $
also got complicated.